# Confluent Schema Registry on Client side with RecordNameStrategy

Tags: confluent-schema-registry

I am new to Confluent Schema Registry and I am trying to understand the RecordNameStrategy:

I currently use the KafkaAvroDeserializer and when registering to the registry, the information is fetched from the generated class and schema.

How does this work on the client side for e.g. with KafkaAvroSerializer. Where does the information come from there, especially with a different language like Python?

Do you have to pay attention to something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Java implementation I have seen that a magic byte is coded into the message with which the schema can be found.